# How can i filter consecutive data rows btw NaN rows in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe that looks like the following. There are >=1 consecutive rows where y_l is populated and y_h is NaN and vice versa.
When we have more than 1 consecutive populated lines between the NaNs we only want to keep the one with the lowest y_l or the highest y_h. 
e.g. on the df below from the last 3 rows we would only keep the 2nd and discard the other two.
What would be a smart way to implement that?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'y_l': [NaN, 97,95,98,NaN],'y_h': [90, NaN,NaN,NaN,95]}, columns=['y_l','y_h'])

>>> df

   y_l   y_h
0  NaN   90.0
1  97.0  NaN
2  95.0  NaN
3  98.0  NaN
4  NaN   95
```

Desired result:

```
     y_l  y_h
0    NaN  90.0
1    95.0  NaN
2    NaN   95
```

Comment: seems like you do not need to consider x_h and x_l

Comment: What is `btw`?? Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: Have you tried anything since the last time you asked this?

Comment: correct the x_h and x_l is irrelevant. actually ill remove it for clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need create new column or `Series` for distinguish each consecutives and then use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggreagte by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), last for change order of columns use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
a = df['y_l'].isnull()
b = a.ne(a.shift()).cumsum()
df = (df.groupby(b, as_index=False)
        .agg({'y_l':'min', 'y_h':'max'})
        .reindex(columns=['y_l','y_h']))
print (df)
    y_l   y_h
0   NaN  90.0
1  95.0   NaN
2   NaN  95.0
```

Detail:

```
print (b)
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    3
Name: y_h, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you had more columns?
for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [NaN, 15,20,25,NaN],'y_l': [NaN,    97,95,98,NaN],'y_h': [90, NaN,NaN,NaN,95]}, columns=['A','y_l','y_h'])
>>>df

     A      y_l     y_h
0   NaN     NaN     90.0
1   15.0    97.0    NaN
2   20.0    95.0    NaN
3   25.0    98.0    NaN
4   NaN     NaN     95.0
```

How could you keep the values in column A after filtering out the irrelevant rows as below?

```
     A      y_l     y_h
0   NaN     NaN     90.0
1   20.0    95.0    NaN
2   NaN     NaN     95.0
```